# inserting 3d .obj into scene with godot code

Tags: godot

I am trying to write some code, where upon running it will place a 3d obj. It is a tool to help build a map before game runtine.

It is a simple 3d obj arrayMesh I am trying to add to a tscn file.

In godot I have:

```
@tool
extends EditorScript

# scene to 3d obj to
var scene = preload("res://main.tscn").instantiate()

# load 3d pbject
var grass = preload("res://map/Models/OBJ format/grass.obj")

func _run():
    # get node to append map to
    var map_holder_node = scene.get_node("map_holder")
    
    map_holder_node.add_child(grass.new())
```

I get the error:

```
res://map/generate_map.gd:14 - Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'new' in base 'ArrayMesh'.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The error message refers to line 17 in your script, however, you only shared 15 lines of code in your question.

Comment: You are right @liggiorgio - I just removed some comments I made for myself here in the example, so that line number should refierence the `map_holder_node.add_child(grass.new())` line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything you `load` or `preload` is a `Resource`. That includes, for example, `PackedScene`, which you `instantiate`, and `Script`s which you usually create with `new` (in general you create instances of classes with `new`, and `Script`s are classes).

In this case you have an `ArrayMesh`, which is neither a `PackedScene` nor a `Script`.

I understand you want some `Node`, given that you are trying to use `add_child`. So the question is: what kind of `Node` can hold a `ArrayMesh`?

I want to highlight that Godot is not making assumptions about how `Resource`s will be used. For example, you could create a script that exports a variable of `ArrayMesh` so you can set it. However, I don't think that is what you want.

Well, `ArrayMesh` is a kind of `Mesh`, and here are three build-in `Node` types that can use it: `CSGMesh3D`, `GPUParticles3D` and `MeshInstance3D`.

The most usual case is `MeshInstance3D`, which you create and then set its`mesh` property:

```
    var mesh_instance := MeshInstance3D.new()
    mesh_instance.mesh = grass
    map_holder_node.add_child(mesh_instance)
```

You might want to set other of the properties of `MeshInstance3D`, but I cannot guess which or how.

And, of course, using the `ArrayMesh` directly in a `Node` is not the only thing you can do with it. For example, you might use it to create other resources... Notably, you might be interested in `MultiMesh`.